# Oracle 11g - Selecting multiple records from a table column

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I was just wondering how you select multiple records from a table column. Please see below the query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT DEPARTMENT_NAME, CITY, COUNTRY_NAME
FROM OEHR_DEPARTMENTS
NATURAL JOIN OEHR_EMPLOYEES 
NATURAL JOIN OEHR_LOCATIONS 
NATURAL JOIN OEHR_COUNTRIES
WHERE JOB_ID = 'SA_MAN' AND JOB_ID = 'SA_REP'
;
```

Basically, I want to be able to `select` records from the table column I have, however when you use `AND` it only displays SA_MAN and not SA_REP. I have also tried to use OR and it displays no rows selected. How would I actually be able to select both Job ID's without it just displaying one or the other.

Sorry this may sound like a stupid question (and probably not worded right), but I am pretty new to Oracle 11g SQL.

Comment: Check your `where` clause. You have done natural join, it should work fine (believing in whatever the table name is given). Try to mention the specific table from which it is supposed to filter.

Answer (score 0):

For your own comfort while debugging, I suggest you to use inner joins instead of natual joins.

That `where` clause is confusing, if not utterly wrong, because you don't make clear which tables' `JOB_ID` should be filtered. Use inner joins, give aliases to tables, and refer to those aliases in the where clause.

```
select  distinct DEPARTMENT_NAME, CITY, COUNTRY_NAME
from    OEHR_DEPARTMENTS t1
join    OEHR_EMPLOYEES t2
  on    ...
join    OEHR_LOCATIONS t3
  on    ...
join    OEHR_COUNTRIES t4
  on    ...
where   tn.JOB_ID = 'SA_MAN' AND tm.JOB_ID = 'SA_REP'
```

After rephrasing your query somehow like this, you'll have a clearer view on the logical operator you'll have to use in the `where` clause, which I bet will be an `OR`.

**EDIT (after more details were given)**

To list the departments that employ staff with both 'SA_MAN' and 'SA_REP' job_id, you have to join the departments table with the employees twice, once with the filter `job_id='SA_MAN'` and once with `job_id='SA_REP'`

```
select  distinct DEPARTMENT_NAME, CITY, COUNTRY_NAME
from    OEHR_DEPARTMENTS t1
join    OEHR_EMPLOYEES t2
on      t1.department_id = t2.department_id --guessing column names
join    OEHR_EMPLOYEES t3
  on    t1.department_id = t3.department_id --guessing column names
join    OEHR_LOCATIONS t4
  on    t1.location_id = t4.location_id --guessing column names
join    OEHR_COUNTRIES t5
  on    t4.country_id = t5.country_id --guessing column names
where   t2.job_id = 'SA_MAN' and t3.job_id = 'SA_REP'
order by 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try. If I still error I'll give much more detail

Comment: How do you know JOB_ID comes from two different tables?

Comment: Still seems to be erroring out. It might be me being stupid....and JOB_ID comes from a table called OEHR_EMPLOYEES.

Comment: Please give more details about the query that you're using and about the error it gives.

@BobC I assumed it came from two different tables because OP stated using `AND` resulted in some rows being returned. If the column is the same, the conjunction of two conditions will always be false.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Okay so the question to the query is:
For each department that employs staff with a job id of ‘SA_MAN’ and also employs staff with a job id of ‘SA_REP’ list the department name, along with its associated country name and city. The output should be ordered in ascending sequence of department name within city within country name.

The error I get is - ORA-00942 The table or view does not exist.

I have followed what you advised previously by giving the tables alias's but then it errors with the WHERE clause. Alternativly do you have an email/chat as it might

Comment: First of all, that error means the table doesn't exists, so you either mispelled its name or haven't it defined in your database.

Then, that requirement needs you to join the department with employee twice, once for the 'SA_REP' job_id and one for the 'SA_MAN' job id. It's not something you can achieve in a single join. I'll edit my answer with something closer to what you need.

Comment: I see. Hmmmm, I'll have a look at the edit you suggested and will re-try

Comment: The edited query you provided doesn't error out but it is still only giving me one result. I have had a look at the Tables and SA_MAN has around 6 entries and SA_REP has 4. But it only seems to be display the SA_MAN results.